# If I modify an existing product in a way that broadens its use, can I patent the whole thing or just my modification?

Tags: patentability

For example, if I take an existing pet training device and make modifications that allow it to be used in a new way (but also for pet training), can I patent the entire device, or just my modifications? My modifications can be removed (except for the attachments) to allow the device to be used as it was originally intended, then easily re-attached for the new use.

Comment: You might want to look into something sometimes known as a "Continuation Claim" http://www.bios.net/daisy/patentlens/2645.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case of attachment, you can only patent your modifications along with its other uses. Not the entire product (i.e. pet training gadget).

I don't have much background in patents but, for what I know, you can patent the modification you made under your name. It can be listed in original product's patent as a cited patent (if it was a critical modification which the original product owner would like to add). 
You can even license the original product and create a new along with your modification. You can earn a good profit without harming any law.

Comment: Need to be a little careful here. If the original device is patented, you probably can't just modify it and sell it even if you get a patent. The original patent exists and protects the original device. You'll need a license to get he original device to market yours.